# Fit catalog Image in product image in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

i have one issue that dont know how to resolve. I have a [Woocommerce shop](https://statementmadeapparel.com/product-category/womens-tees-tanks/), and its working fine. But images in catalog shop shows cutted at bottom and at top, so image is not showed in full size. To explain better, this is how need to looks that image:

[image]

and this is how looks in my shop:

[image]

What i tryed:

1. Get original image filesize from theme demo and set to my site too.
2. Regenerate Thumbnails via plugin for that.

But images are still cropped at head and bottom.. I want to show in full size but fit in that place. Someone to help me? Im using Woocommerce 3.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

First Step go to wordpress customize and then chose woocommerce then Product image and chose Uncropped

after that you need Regenerate Thumbnails clear your cash and you should have Uncropped picture

[image]

and you might need plugin Square Thumbnails plugin if you have mixed picture sizes to make sure they will fit inside the Square without an issue

for old version of woocommerce   unchecked the hard crop box

[image]

Comment: Hi im using woocommerce 3.0.1 that that settings are from Woo 3.3.X. I still can configure image settings from Products > Display > Image Settings

Comment: @JoeKooker i have added the pic for the old version of woocommerce

Comment: I can use your settings that you have used ? will be ok ?

Comment: @JoeKooker no uncheck the hard crop if you are checking the hard crop that mean woocommerce will cust the pic in order to fit with that size that you chosed

Comment: Yes i uncheck hard crop, and now image are shown in full size but its not all the same.. This is my current configuration:

https://i.imgur.com/Kak5cMg.png?1 Pls check the store now how it looks.

Comment: this case you need this plugin ( Square Thumbnails  ) to make the pic fit inside the Square 

 https://wordpress.org/plugins/square-thumbnails/

Comment: Tryed that , but dont changed nothing in images. Looks like its outdated, and not working anymore. Last time tested on 4.8.6 . I use 4.9.4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168327/discussion-between-kashalo-and-joe-kooker).